# How do i fill values into table, which are got from mysql database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html, date, html-table

**Problem Statement:** 
Fill the time values into table with respect to dates using PHP, MySQL and HTML.

**Overview:** Developing a web application to manage time-sheet of employees,

1. User selects Monday date and all the other week dates gets filled automatically.
2. User fills his/her time taken for the particular task and submit ( each end of the day s/he does that)
3. Lets say user fills and submits the time-sheet on Monday, and logs in on Tuesday to web app, when user selects the date and click on 'SubmitDate' button all the previous date values ( Monday's) should get filled and should get freezes ( non-editable).
   [image: time-sheet]
   **Code(for table logic)**

   Tasks
               Monday 
               Tuesday
               Wednesday
               Thursday
               Friday 
               Saturday
               Sunday

   ```
         <tr> 
            <th>DATES</th>
            <?php //while ($a <7):?>
            <th> <?php //$output = getStartAndEndDate(2, 2015); echo $output?> </th>
            <?php //$a++; ?>
            <?php //endwhile ?>
         </tr>


   <?php $sdate = $_SESSION['start_date1'];?>
       <?php $parts = explode('-', $sdate);?> 
        <tr> 
        <th>DATES</th>


        <?php $year=$parts[0]?>
        <?php $time = strtotime("$parts[2].$parts[1].$year", time());?>
        <?php $day = date('w', $time); ?>
        <?php $time += ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;?>
        <?php $return[0] = date('Y-n-j', $time);?>
        <th> <?php echo "$return[0] <br>"; ?> </th>

        <?php $m = 0;?>
        <?php while ($m<6):?>
        <?php $i=1; ?>
        <!-- <?php $time// += ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;?> -->
        <?php $time += $i*24*3600; ?>
        <?php $return[1] = date('Y-n-j', $time); ?>
        <!-- <?php //echo "$return[1] <br>"; ?> -->
        <th> <?php echo "$return[1] <br>"; ?> </th>
        <?php $m++; ?>
        <?php endwhile ?>
   </thead>

   <?php foreach ($separateTaskList as $val1):?>
       <tr>
           <th> <?php  echo $val1?></th>
           <td contenteditable="true"> 0</td>
           <td contenteditable="true"> 0</td>
           <td contenteditable="true"> 0</td>
           <td contenteditable="true"> 0</td>
           <td contenteditable="true"> 0</td>
           <td contenteditable="true"> 0</td>
           <td contenteditable="true"> 0</td>
       </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
   </table>

   <div class="container" style="text-align:center">
   <button style="" onclick="actionSend()" class="btn-default-submit submitbtn" align="center">SUBMIT</button></div>
   ```

**Code( to push values to db):**

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO timesheet_details 
(emp_id, tmsheet_week_start_dt, tmsheet_activity_dt, project_id, task_id, 
activity_tm_spent_min, tmsheet_status, tmsheet_submit_dt, tmsheet_approve_dt, tmsheet_approver_id ) 
 VALUES 
($emp_id, '$tmsheet_week_start_dt', '$tmsheet_week_start_dt', '$project_id', '$task_id' , $_totalMinutes, 'Notapproved', '$tmsheet_week_start_dt', '$tmsheet_week_start_dt', 1000 );");

$stmt->execute();
```

**Question:** How do i retrieve the data and fill on the same table according to date?

I am happy to any missing detail if any. 
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After you use the following code

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO timesheet_details 
(emp_id, tmsheet_week_start_dt, tmsheet_activity_dt, project_id, task_id, 
activity_tm_spent_min, tmsheet_status, tmsheet_submit_dt, tmsheet_approve_dt, tmsheet_approver_id ) 
 VALUES 
($emp_id, '$tmsheet_week_start_dt', '$tmsheet_week_start_dt', '$project_id', '$task_id' , $_totalMinutes, 'Notapproved', '$tmsheet_week_start_dt', '$tmsheet_week_start_dt', 1000 );");

$stmt->execute();
```

Try and do a fetch all which you can retrieve into the fields. For example do a fetch all and grab the values  from the database .

Example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("Select * FROM timesheet_details WHERE emp_id = $emp_id");
$stmt->execute
```

Then in HTML just get the echo the different days.

Comment: Thank you, i am facing problem with HTML table coding, how to display it on the same table, could you help me with that please.

Comment: Try reload the page with the new values in the table.